# Здравствуйте, не понимаю почему не работает код в питоне, посмотрите, пожалуйтса

Tags: python

Нужно посчитать сколько существует двузначных чисел, у которых сумма цифр равна сумме цифр при умножение на n (1<=n<=10) Например :
(При умножении двузначных чисел на 2 не меняют сумму цифр такие числа: 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 90 99.)

Мне кажется, что вроде всё правильно написал, а программа работает неверно. При вводе n=2 должно выдавать: 10

```
n = int(input())
counter = 0
for i in range(1, 100):
    o = i // 10
    d = i % 10
    o_1 = (n * i) // 10
    d_1 = (n * i) % 10 #36 72
    if i * n < 100:
        if d + o == d_1 + o_1:
            counter += 1
    else:
        s_1 = (n * i) // 10 % 10  #104
        if d + o == d_1 + o_1 + s_1:
            counter += 1
print(counter)
```

[Ссылка на задание](https://www.e-olymp.com/uk/problems/7338)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я вижу 2 ошибки.

1. Числа должны быть двузначные, а цикл у вас от 1 `for i in range(1, 100)`. Должен быть от 10.
2. `s_1` вы считаете неправильно. Т.к. программа попала в этот `else` блок, то для трехзначного числа у вас `o_1` будет больше или равен 10. Тогда `s_1` (совсем старшая цифра) должна считаться от `o_1` как результат дальнейшего деления на 10. А `o_1` (средняя цифра) - её нужно пересчитать как остаток от деления её же на 10.

```
        s_1 = o_1 // 10
        o_1 = o_1 % 10
```

Либо, если оставить вашу формулу для `s_1` как есть, тогда она олицетворяет среднюю цифру, и `o_1` надо высчитать для старшей:

```
        o_1 = (n * i) // 10 // 10
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, уже второй раз мне помогаете) Искренне вам благодарен!

Comment: @nikitasokolov [как принято говорить "спасибо" на SO (StackOverflow)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814) ;)

Comment: у него код настолько запутанно сделан, что очень сложно понять где там реальные ошибки.

Answer (score 2):

Не проще в отдельной функции сделать подсчет суммы то? Примерно так вот

```
def sumnum(i):
    sum=i%10
    temp=i//10
    while(temp):
        sum+=temp%10
        temp=temp//10
    return sum

n = int(input())
counter = 0
for i in range(10, 100):
    if (sumnum(i)==sumnum(i*n)):
        print("%d %d %d"%(i,i*n,sumnum(i)))
        counter+=1

print(counter)
```

Comment: у автора вопроса стоит задача посчитать сумму цифр только двузначных чисел. об этом говорит, в том числе, это условие в его коде  `if i * n < 100`  .

Comment: а каким образом более общая функция выполнит хуже поставленную автором задачу то? Она от этого неоптимальной стала или что?

Answer (score 1):

Можно так, дополнительно выводятся числа:

```
def sum_digits(number):
    res = 0
    while number:
        res += number % 10
        number //= 10
    return res

n = int(input())
nums = list(filter(lambda i: sum_digits(i) == sum_digits(i * n), range(10, 100)))
print(nums)
print(len(nums))
```